# (Swift) Expand and Collapse tableview cell when tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

Good Morning

I created a custom TableViewCell, which internally has a CollectionViewCell and a directional arrow. I was able to make the cell expand and collapse however I would like it when I expand one cell and I click on another one the previous collapse. Example: If cell is expanded and cell is tapped, I want cell to contract and cell to expand at the same time. So that only one cell can be in its expanded state in any given moment changing the targeting arrow.

Example:

If cellA is expanded and cellB is tapped, I want cellA to contract and cellB to expand at the same time. So that only one cell can be in its expanded state in any given moment changing the targetting arrow.

My code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {






    switch(selectedIndexPath)
    {

    case nil:

        let cell = myTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.arrowImagem.image = UIImage(named:"content_arrow2")
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath



    default:
        if selectedIndexPath! == indexPath
        {

            let cell = myTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
            cell.arrowImagem.image = UIImage(named:"content_arrow")
            //cell.reloadInputViews()
            selectedIndexPath = nil

        }


    }

    self.myTableView.beginUpdates()

    self.myTableView.reloadData()


    //myTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)

    self.myTableView.endUpdates()

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {





    let index = indexPath

    if selectedIndexPath != nil{
        if(index == selectedIndexPath)
        {
            return 147
        }
        else{
            return 67
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return 67
    }



}
```

Comment: Sorry i dont translate the beggining of question

good morning

I created a custom TableViewCell, which internally has a CollectionViewCell and a directional arrow.

I was able to make the cell expand and collapse however I would like it when I expand one cell and I click on another one the previous collapse.

Example:

If cell is expanded and cell is tapped, I want cell to contract and cell to expand at the same time. So that only one cell can be in its expanded state in any given moment changing the targeting arrow.

Comment: You can always [edit] your question at any time if you need to fix or add things.

Comment: Thanks for the info Eric :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that but you need to do some coding. First of all detect when a row is selected (keep the Index Path of the selected row in a variable). When a row is selected you will add the index path of the new selected row and that of the previously selected (that you have in the variable) in an array that you pass to the tableView reloadRows from inside didSelectRowAt, this function will force redrawing of the two rows and the heightForRowAt function will be called to get the height of both rows, in heightForRowAt you will check the currently selected row (do you remember the variable I mentioned earlier?) and return the expanded height for that, while for the others you return the collapsed height. You should get the result you want. Hope that will help.

Comment: Thanks Sergio i'll try your solution

Comment: Thanks Sergio with your idea I built a function that solved my problem :)

Comment: I'm happy to hear that. Good job!

Comment: if you post the code you used it will be helpful for others @Sergiob

Comment: I should write the code from scratch. I'll probably do it in the next days (now I'm busy with a large project), but it is not so difficult, if you follow the instructions I wrote in my post in less then 10 minutes you'll get the result... maybe Jose could post his code...

Answer (score 0):

You can implement most of the functionality in the `didSet` handler:

```
var selectedIndexPath: IndexPath? {
    didSet {
        guard indexPath != oldValue else {
           return
        }

        if let oldValue = oldValue {
            let cell = myTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? TableViewCell
            cell?.arrowImagem.image = UIImage(named:"content_arrow")
        }

        if let indexPath = indexPath {
            let cell = myTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? TableViewCell
            cell?.arrowImagem.image = UIImage(named:"content_arrow2")
        }

        let rowsToUpdate = [indexPath, oldValue].compactMap { $0 }

        self.myTableView.beginUpdates()

        // I don't think you actually need to reload rows here but keeping your code here...
        self.myTableView.reloadRows(at: rowsToUpdate, with: .automatic)
        self.myTableView.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

and then in your `didSelect`:

```
if indexPath == selectedIndexPath {
   selectedIndexPath = nil
} else {
   selectedIndexPath = indexPath
}
```

(written without testing)

Comment: need help i have a same scenario

Comment: @DilipTiwari Then ask a question about your *specific* problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50422132/how-to-expand-and-collapse-cell-in-swift  i have posted this question

Comment: @DilipTiwari Your question will be probably closed as too broad. We are here to help with specific problems not to write the whole code for you.

Comment: but bro basically give idea about that i never worked with that scenario